# Eclipse error by debugging  strlen

Tags: c

This program crashes at the point `i=(strlen(data));` with the message

> No source available for "strlen() "

But Why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main (void) { 
    char data[]="Hallo";
    char buffer[100];
    if (strlen(data)!=0)
    {
        size_t i=0;
        i=(strlen(data));
        snprintf(buffer,i,"Data: %s \n",data);
        return strlen(data)+1;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: This is a question about an error message so you need to give your compiler and development environment name and version.

Comment: It's a very strange program, indeed. I ran it, and it doesn't crash. It returns a status value of 6 (`strlen("Hallo") + 1`), but it doesn't crash. It doesn't look like it contains any obvious actual errors, either. Are you sure it crashes?

Comment: The parentheses around `strlen(data)` aren't needed. This probably has nothing to do with the error message.

Comment: You should also provide the complete, unedited, error message. Please edit your question to add it.

Comment: On an unrelated note, returning `-1` from `main` tells the calling program (shell, command prompt, whatever) that your program ended in an error. Anything but zero is normally considered an error by the calling environment.

Comment: The return values are not portable. For portable code, use `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE`, defined in <stdlib.h>. This also probably has nothing to do with the error message.

Comment: Another side note: Stop recomputing `strlen(data)`!

Comment: The error message you cite does not sound like a crash. More like a debugger trying to step into a system library function.

Comment: I debbuged  it with Eclipse and I got this message, so it don't crash but don't work

Comment: @Arkadiy I think we have a winner

Comment: @Arkadiy Right, that's it! Post an answer.

Comment: @Arkadiy: Right, but *why* does the debugger step into the system library function? I suspect it's because of a segmentation fault.

Comment: @Arkadiy of course your right, Post an answer

Comment: Downvotes (not me): probably because you said your program crashed, and it didn't.  Eclipse gives you an error message - not the same thing.

Comment: @cdarke That would be a sane reason

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message you cite does not sound like a crash. More like a debugger trying to step into a system library function.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the cause of the problem is

```
snprintf(buffer,i,"Data: %s \n",data);
```

The `i` here is the "buffer size". `i` is also the length of `data`. So you're writing a string to a buffer which is longer than the buffer size. The effect is that [`snprintf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) truncates the output, so not the entire `data` string will be written.

In fact, `Data:` is six characters long, that's longer than `i` (5). So maybe what's happening is that snprintf never makes use of the `%s` modified, which somehow breaks the stack?

Try replacing `i` with `sizeof(buffer)` and see whether that works better.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran this program in Eclipse, and it works fine.  It sounds like you are stepping through the code line-by-line and when you get to the `strlen` call you do a "Step-Into"(F5) instead of "Step Over"(F6).   So Eclipse is trying to debug `strlen`.

Either way, this is an Eclipse issue and I suggest you add an `Eclipse` tag to the question.